# Rewrite URL in .htaccess if it contains %2F

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite any URL that contains %2F. Here's an example of the URL I'm trying to recognize:

http://shop.myurl.com/%2FOakley-004046-C-Wire-P3536.aspx

I need to rewrite this URL as:

http://www.myurl.com/search.php?search_query=Oakley-004046-C-Wire-P3536

The things the rewrite needs to do:
-Change the subdomain from shop. to www.
-Strip out the %2F
-Strip off the .aspx
-Inject search.php?search_query=

In addition, I need a rule for any URL that DOESN'T contain %2F and just swap the subdomain from shop. to www.

It seems like this should be possible, but I'm no .htaccess jock. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //(.*)\.aspx
RewriteRule ^ http://www.myurl.com/search.php?search_query=%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\ //(.*)\.aspx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for URLs that do not contain %2F.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the answer [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3279075.htm). The entire URL is being ignore because a naked %2F is only allowed in a query string, not a URL. Ideas anyone? Fixing bad "old" URLs is not an option. I just need to redirect them.